# Java microservice integration with mainframe, special character in mainframe is breaking my program, how to deal with it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ibm-mq, mainframe

I have a microservice in java with spring boot.
Which receives payment orders, processes them and publishes them in the MQ queue.

Who consumes from the MQ queue is the mainframe, after consuming the message from the MQ queue that contains an attribute with a special character, it breaks the execution of the program in the mainframe.

Is there a way to handle this in my java microservice, convert the special character to a format that doesn't break my program on the mainframe?

Example of the message that is posted to the MQ queue and is crashing my mainframe program when it consumes the message:

```
{
   "id": "2058169d-a658-4f04-bce7-82f4be859f9e",
   "price": "15.17",
   "product": "t-shirt",
   "date": "2022-11-17",
   "company_name": ""
}
```

The attribute that is breaking my program on the mainframe is the **company_name**.

- U+1d4a6
 - U+1d4c9
 - U+1d4cf

Is there a way to convert the **company_name** to:

```
{
   "id": "2058169d-a658-4f04-bce7-82f4be859f9e",
   "price": "15.17",
   "product": "t-shirt",
   "date": "2022-11-17",
   "company_name": "Ktz"
}
```

I'm looking for a way to convert the special character to a way that doesn't break my mainframe program.

Comment: If you know the character range of the input, you can create a `Map` of Mathematical script to plain ASCII.  Why is the input company name Mathematical script?

Comment: You could use the ASCIIFoldingFilter from lucene
https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_1_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ASCIIFoldingFilter.html

Comment: If you are properly describing the message as for example UTF-8 (CCSID 1208) in the MQMD.CCSID and the mainframe issues a GET with convert or you have CONVERT(YES) on your SDR channel then those charcuterie which can't be represented in EBCDIC will be converted to a default substitution character,  but this is probably not what you want given it is a company name.  Better to correct the string before you send it to MQ.

Comment: @JoshMc I love the idea of a "charcuterie" being represented in EBCDIC but to be serious, are you saying that there should be no failure as the mainframe OS should smoothly perform substitution?

Comment: A quick and very dirty might be `s = s.replaceAll("\uD835\uDCA6\uD835\uDCC9\uD835\uDCCF", "Ktz");` but a more flexible, solid and maintainable way would probably be to use a `FilterWriter`

Comment: IBM MQ did the conversion, not the mainframe OS.

Comment: I see, but why, if conversion is taking place, is any "crashing" occurring?

Comment: I suspect the application is crashing because the conversion does not result in characters that are expected, i.e. the default substitution character for those codepoints not recognised in the target codepage.